# how to move images on finger touch in android?

Tags: android

I am developing an small application in a android. Before this i had done surfing on internet but i can't get useful material. In this application i have two tabs I had made the these two tabs but I want after click on first tab i want some images these Images can move on right side when user touch it on right and left side when user touch it left means user can slide the images on both left and right by finger. Can anyone suggest me any tutorial or source code so that i can able to do functionality like this.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See [this](http://staticallytyped.wordpress.com/2010/12/02/touch-and-drag-in-android/) blog post on how to do it.  You need to look at [SurfaceView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/SurfaceView.html) and the [onTouchListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnTouchListener.html).  Taken from the blog:

```
              surf.setOnTouchListener( new SurfaceView.OnTouchListener(){
                  public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                     case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                        if( moving ){
                            final int x_new = (int)event.getX();
                            final int y_new = (int)event.getY();
                            mDrawTiles.draw( new DrawLogic(){
                                @Override
                                public void draw(Rect _surface) {
                                    mTiles.setBounds(
                                        x_new - mDrawWidth/2,
                                        y_new - mDrawHeight/2,
                                        x_new + mDrawWidth/2,
                                        y_new + mDrawHeight/2);
                                    }
                                });
                            }
```

Comment: yes, i had use this code But i didn't see anything on the emulator can you suggest any other tutorial

Comment: Other than what you could Google yourself, I have no other tutorial.  I figured it out through trial and error plus reading the Android source code.

Answer (score 0):

```
int x1 = (int) event.getX();       
int y1 = (int) event.getY();

imageobject.layout(x1,x1+(width_of_imageobject),y1,y1+(width_of_imageobject));
```